# how to manage batches for model.provide_groundtruth

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-model-garden

I'm trying to use TensorFlow 2 Object Detection API with a custom dataset for multi classes to train an SSD, I took as base the example provide by the documentation: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/eager_few_shot_od_training_tf2_colab.ipynb
My current problem is when I start the fine tuning:

> InvalidArgumentError: The first dimension of paddings must be the rank
> of inputs[2,2] [6] [Op:Pad]

That seems to be related with the section of model.provide_groundtruth on train_step_fn, as I mention I took my data from a TensorFlow record, I mapped this to a dataset and divide it into batches using padded_batches(tf.data.TFRecordDataset) seems that this is the correct to feed the training with the image but now my problem is the groundtruth because this now is also converted to batches [batch_size,num_detections,coordinate_bbox], is this the problem? any idea on how to fix this issue.
Thanks

P.S. I tried to used the version of modified the pipeline.config file and run the model_main_tf2.py as was in the past with TensorFlow 1 but this method is buggy.

Comment: Just to share with everyone this resolves my issue was that I manage to split the data into batches the images and ground truth correctly but I never convert my labels to one hot vector encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Just to share with everyone this resolves my issue was that I manage to split the data into batches the images and ground truth correctly but I never convert my labels to one hot vector encoding.